# How i can expire the access-token manually or forcefully generated by my own web API

Tags: c#, asp.net, security, oauth, oauth-2.0

I Create a Web API in the asp.net web API its Generate the access-token and store in the browser storage cache or session storage what if someone stole the access-token from the browser he can expose the API Data by using fiddler or Post Man so how can we prevent that issue how can we expire the token manually or forcefully

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The usual mechanism is to introduce refresh tokens. Let the access tokens have a short lifespan, say one day, and have a long lived refresh token request new access tokens every day. The server can then be asked to revoke access for a specific account by disabling the access for a refresh token.

Answer (score 2):

I dont think you can expire an access token generated in that way.  Access tokens are good for the extent of their lifetime. This is why access tokens short lived tokens, normally an hour.

Even having the user revoke their consent is not going to expire an access token.

That being said the OAuth 2.0 Token Revocation [RFC 7009](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7009) specification supplements the core specification with a mechanism to revoke both types of tokens.  A token is a string representing an authorization grant issued by the resource owner to the client.  A revocation request will invalidate the actual token and, if applicable, other tokens based on the same authorization grant and the authorization grant itself.

```
POST /revoke HTTP/1.1
 Host: server.example.com
 Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
 Authorization: Basic czZCaGRSa3F0MzpnWDFmQmF0M2JW

 token=45ghiukldjahdnhzdauz&token_type_hint=access_token
```

But this will probably only work if you are using an Authentication server to get your Access token and if the Authentication server supports this endpoint.   IIR Googles for example only supports revoke of the refresh token not the access token.  This is not a default thing.   I have never implemented it myself it would probably entail storing the access token on the auth server and then testing that somehow rather than having it be a standard JWT.